# Automatic setup of Django development environment

Tags: django

It has been a year since I last setup a new project with Django and I remember automatizing it was pretty painful at the time. When searching the subject these days I can't find anything really helpful.

So, what is the latest in automatic setup of Django local development environment?

By that I mean maybe some orchestration with something like chef or juju to setup a vagrant box or similar to develop on a local system with a database like PostgreSQL and other system level tools (cache, queue...). Maybe with automatic connection to a github repository or equivalent. Anything that would help start developing right away and also deploy the environment on a server without pain.

Does something like that exist today and it has escaped me? Or is it something that still needs to be improved? Setting up a good development environment for Django has changed a lot since the early days of virtual environment and sqlite, and even since a few years ago.

Edit: I have accepted the only answer because... it's the only answer. And it's good enough. But feel free to add any new answer since this one, although interesting, does not satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks what [vagrant-django-template](https://github.com/torchbox/vagrant-django-template) is pretty good solution for you.

Comment: Indeed it looks very good. But let's go further. Although it probably fits my needs well it is yet a ready made environment, not a tool that allows to choose between the most common components for a Django project. If such project exists that's what I am looking for. Otherwise this is a very good start.